# attachment csv file in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app i sending  a file as csv format it's working fine if i open in "neo-office"  but it's not opening properly in "MS-office".
 I am using below code to send csv file

```
NSString *str_mail = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event Name;Event 1\n status;open\nstart date;19-May-2001\nend date;22-May-2001\nno of friends;2\ntotal;2,00 AUDn\n\n"]];
NSData *myData = [str_mail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [mailController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"test.csv"];
```

Comment: what happens if you change type to just csv or ma be even better text - who knows if the file gets changes somewhere because of that.